# Unable to remove older posts

Tags: cron

I am placing this in my theme editor in an attempt to delete posts that are a day or older, but I seem to have done something wrong. When I run it there are still older posts on my front page. I am also using the Cron Manager Plugin. What am I doing wrong?

```
function cron_wp_posts_77c65d7d() {
    // delete FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_type` = 'post'
AND DATE_DIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 1}
add_action( 'wp_posts', 'cron_wp_posts_77c65d7d', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: @Eliot hello, You imported one of my old post on quabr. However i published it by mistake in a first place and deleted it as fast as i could. Could you remove it pls, it could harm me. It's this post: http://5.9.10.113/66163650/outlier-detection-pyod-lscp-how-to-choose-the-right-model-and-improve-the-res

Comment: Antoine553 - Just got back.  Don't recognize the post/code at all and sadly if I did I wouldn't know what to do with it.  Maybe it was an Eliot with one "L"?  Regards,  Elliot

Comment: I did import the code from above, but not from the link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I talked with the person i borrowed the code and it's not really a problem but if you can find a way to delete it, it would be nice. (I'm new at the job and this might be my first mistake, even if it's not a problem it made me stress a lot XD)